# Oracle SQL: check if time is between two instances (excluding dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: sql, oracle, time, oracle-apex

I am building an Oracle APEX application in which journalists can bring in articles, which a director selects for a broadcast, along with a newsreader (who can read the articles if the broadcast is created). I am kind of stuck with the following:
I would like to create an Oracle SQL query which selects the first and last name of a record in the "user" table, when its availability (which is stored in another table, "Beschikbaarheid") meets the given circumstances (user begin time at broadcast day >= broadcast begin time AND user end time at broadcast day <= broadcast end time). 
I myself have written the following query.

```
SELECT voornaam || ' ' || achternaam AS display_value, id AS return_value
FROM Gebruiker
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT Nieuwslezerselectie.nieuwslezerid FROM Nieuwslezerselectie 
WHERE -- other conditions
AND id IN (SELECT gebruikerid 
           FROM Beschikbaarheid 
           WHERE (dag = to_char(to_date(:P91_DATUM,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'Day'))
           AND (to_date(:P91_BEGINTIJD,'HH24:MI') >= to_date(begintijd,'HH24:MI'))
           AND (to_date(:P91_EINDTIJD,'HH24:MI') <= to_date(eindtijd,'HH24:MI'))
          );
```

(Excuse me if you are having trouble reading this, I use Dutch naming. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.)

However, the APEX select list to which this query is linked is not showing anything if the newsreader is available at the time of the broadcast. I think the problem is "Begintijd" and "Eindtijd" are stored as time stamps, as the values should be date-independent (which time stamps are not), but I have no clue how to store them otherwise. As a varchar maybe?

I sincerely hope you have any ideas. Thank you in advance!

Luc

**update 1**

With help I have rewritten the query, it now looks like this:

```
AND id IN (SELECT gebruikerid 
       FROM Beschikbaarheid
       WHERE (dag = to_char(to_date(:P91_DATUM,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Dutch'))
       AND (
            to_date('01-01-2000' || ' ' || to_char(to_timestamp(:P91_BEGINTIJD),'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') 
            BETWEEN
            to_date('01-01-2000' || ' ' || to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
            AND
            to_date('01-01-2000' || ' ' || to_char(eindtijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
           )
       AND (
            to_date('01-01-2000' || ' ' || to_char(to_timestamp(:P91_EINDTIJD),'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') 
            BETWEEN 
            to_date('01-01-2000' || ' ' || to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
            AND
            to_date('01-01-2000' || ' ' || to_char(eindtijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
           )
      );
```

However, I am now getting the *ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format* error when trying to access the page. I haven't discovered what causes that error yet. Does anyone have any clues?

**update 2**

Now I am confused. It turned out I didn't need to_char etc. for my page variables, so I removed those (to_char etc.). Now I am normally send to the correct page, but the last value I entered in the "set these items / with these values" text fields on the previous page, isn't send. This is what I have in these text fields right now:

[image: set items with values]

In this image, P85_BEGINTIJD isn't send. I also switched the values around, but that didn't make a difference. Is there a limit to the amount of values you can send with a request, or something?

Comment: What are the datatypes in table `Beschikbaarheid`?  Can you show some sample data?  What happens if you run your sub-select on it's own - do you get any rows back.   What is the purpose of your first `NOT IN` statement, I can't see how it fits your question?

Comment: What are the values of `dag`? Does the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` match? Note, `TO_CHAR(..., 'Day')` makes a right-padding with spaces, try `TO_CHAR(..., 'fmDay')`

Comment: WW: The NOT IN is not really relevant to this question, I guess I will have to leave it out. I just copy-pasted the whole lov source code. About Beschikbaarheid, that table includes a FK userid, the name of the day in the week (in Dutch) and a begin and end time (both timestamps atm).

Comment: there is no limit in your sql statement. I have seen a sql demonstration with 143 (really!) lines.....please supply some demo data and the relevant database schema, so we can test/reproduce an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so eventually, I was able to solve it. In my last update, the only lasting problem was that some variables weren't send to the next page. I wasn't able to find the root cause of the problem, so I did a workaround.

The only variable that was sent normally to the next page is P91_UITZENDING (the PK of Uitzending). Luckily, the other variables I needed (begintijd, eindtijd and datum) are attributes of Uitzending so I was able to derive them with statements like this in the source of the corresponding page item:

```
SELECT to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI')
-- replace with eindtijd for eindtijd, and for date: to_char(datum,'DD-MON-YYYY')
FROM Uitzending
WHERE id = :P91_UITZENDING
```

And the final SQL query for the select box:

```
SELECT voornaam || ' ' || achternaam AS display_value, id AS return_value
FROM Gebruiker
WHERE -- Other statements
AND id IN (SELECT gebruikerid 
           FROM Beschikbaarheid
           WHERE (dag = to_char(to_date(:P91_DATUM,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'fmDay','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Dutch'))
           AND (
                to_date('01-01-2000' || :P91_BEGINTIJD,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') 
                BETWEEN
                to_date('01-01-2000' || to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
                AND
                to_date('01-01-2000' || to_char(eindtijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
               )
           AND (
                to_date('01-01-2000' || :P91_EINDTIJD,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') 
                BETWEEN 
                to_date('01-01-2000' || to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
                AND
                to_date('01-01-2000' || to_char(eindtijd,'HH24:MI'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')
               )
          );
```

I still don't know why begintijd, eindtijd and datum weren't send the normal way, but at least it is working now.

Thank you all for your thinking and help!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use timestamps. se a date field, which includes date and time, 
more info about date fields in oracle:
[Oracle Data types, see paragraph Overview of DATE Datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847)

Comment: Yes, I do use date fields in my application, but this (it is a timetable, really) is not really date-specific. I converted the values to date in the given code with only time values, but I think it is still getting the dd/mm/yyyy values (?).

Comment: think? check what you are thinking, test with a simple sql statement if you get what you think you get. I  am not an experienced oracle user, (only used for 1 simple application only), but breaking down your sql and then check the result with the expected one, made many things clear for me. But still, i should prefer a timetable with datatype of date and retrieve values as a time only format. Also check the oracle settings for date-time settings. You have to make it locally to NL. I think you have a problem with different date/time settings. I rememeber I had troubles with it too.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Lama,you are right, it should havebeen a comment,not an answer

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you have two columns with data type *TIMESTAMP* and you need to constraint it with a parameter, **but using only the hour an minute** part of it.

The simplest possible way to do it is use a string parameter in format HH:MI

```
 select begintijd, to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI') begintijd_hhmi, 
 eindtijd, to_char(eindtijd,'HH24:MI') eindtijd_hhmi from tst
 where '22:00' between to_char(begintijd,'HH24:MI')  and to_char(eindtijd,'HH24:MI')
 ;
```

Note that you use *to_char* with the date mask **HH24:MI** to get rid of the not relevant part of the date/time.

A probable better and more flexible way is to use **INTERVAL**s.

```
 with t2 as (
  select 
  begintijd, begintijd - trunc(begintijd) begintijd_hhmi, 
  eindtijd, eindtijd - trunc(eindtijd) eindtijd_hhmi from tst)
 select * from t2
 where INTERVAL '22:00' HOUR TO MINUTE between begintijd_hhmi  and  eindtijd_hhmi
 ;
```

You use the difference of the timestamp and the truncated timestamp to calculate the interval (of hour and minutes). Note though, that if the timestamp can contain seconds or fractions of it, you may need to trim them out, e.g. with

```
 NumToDsInterVal(60*extract(hour from begintijd)+extract(minute from begintijd),'MINUTE') begintijd_hhmi
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this tomorrow. Though I don't think this will solve the problem that parameters aren't send?